# Where is Android.OS.BundleStub?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, in-app-billing

I'd like to implement in-app billing in my Xamarin.Android app, and have added IInAppBillingService.aidl to my project, which generates IInAppBillingService.cs.  When I try to build the app, I get the following error:

```
IInAppBillingService.cs(59,59): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BundleStub' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.OS'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I can't find any information about this error and the Xamarin forums have been silent about it. I assume, like the error message says, that I just need to add an assembly reference, but I have no idea what assembly I'm missing. Has anyone gotten this to work?

EDIT: Here is the file generated by Xamarin Studio, if there's no such thing as BundleStub then why is it referenced 4 times (lines 75, 204, 231, 257)?

```
// This file is automatically generated and not supposed to be modified.
using System;
using Boolean = System.Boolean;
using String = System.String;
using List = Android.Runtime.JavaList;
using Map = Android.Runtime.JavaDictionary;
using Android.OS;

namespace Com.Android.Vending.Billing
{
    public interface IInAppBillingService : global::Android.OS.IInterface
    {
        int IsBillingSupported (int apiVersion, String packageName, String type);
        global::Android.OS.Bundle GetSkuDetails (int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, global::Android.OS.Bundle skusBundle);
        global::Android.OS.Bundle GetBuyIntent (int apiVersion, String packageName, String sku, String type, String developerPayload);
        global::Android.OS.Bundle GetPurchases (int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, String continuationToken);
        int ConsumePurchase (int apiVersion, String packageName, String purchaseToken);
    }

    public abstract class IInAppBillingServiceStub : global::Android.OS.Binder, global::Android.OS.IInterface, Com.Android.Vending.Billing.IInAppBillingService
    {
        const string descriptor = "com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService";
        public IInAppBillingServiceStub ()
        {
            this.AttachInterface (this, descriptor);
        }

        public static Com.Android.Vending.Billing.IInAppBillingService AsInterface (global::Android.OS.IBinder obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;
            var iin = (global::Android.OS.IInterface) obj.QueryLocalInterface (descriptor);
            if (iin != null && iin is Com.Android.Vending.Billing.IInAppBillingService)
                return (Com.Android.Vending.Billing.IInAppBillingService) iin;
            return new Proxy (obj);
        }

        public global::Android.OS.IBinder AsBinder ()
        {
            return this;
        }

        protected override bool OnTransact (int code, global::Android.OS.Parcel data, global::Android.OS.Parcel reply, int flags)
        {
            switch (code) {
            case global::Android.OS.BinderConsts.InterfaceTransaction:
                reply.WriteString (descriptor);
                return true;

            case TransactionIsBillingSupported: {
                data.EnforceInterface (descriptor);
                int arg0 = default (int);
                arg0 = data.ReadInt ();
                String arg1 = default (String);
                arg1 = data.ReadString ();
                String arg2 = default (String);
                arg2 = data.ReadString ();
                var result = this.IsBillingSupported (arg0, arg1, arg2);
                reply.WriteInt (result);
                data.WriteInt (arg0);
                data.WriteString (arg1);
                data.WriteString (arg2);
                return true;
                }

            case TransactionGetSkuDetails: {
                data.EnforceInterface (descriptor);
                int arg0 = default (int);
                arg0 = data.ReadInt ();
                String arg1 = default (String);
                arg1 = data.ReadString ();
                String arg2 = default (String);
                arg2 = data.ReadString ();
                global::Android.OS.Bundle arg3 = default (global::Android.OS.Bundle);
                arg3 = global::Android.OS.BundleStub.AsInterface (data.ReadStrongBinder ());
                var result = this.GetSkuDetails (arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
                if (result != null) { reply.WriteInt (1); result.WriteToParcel (reply, global::Android.OS.ParcelableWriteFlags.ReturnValue); } else reply.WriteInt (0);
                data.WriteInt (arg0);
                data.WriteString (arg1);
                data.WriteString (arg2);
                return true;
                }

            case TransactionGetBuyIntent: {
                data.EnforceInterface (descriptor);
                int arg0 = default (int);
                arg0 = data.ReadInt ();
                String arg1 = default (String);
                arg1 = data.ReadString ();
                String arg2 = default (String);
                arg2 = data.ReadString ();
                String arg3 = default (String);
                arg3 = data.ReadString ();
                String arg4 = default (String);
                arg4 = data.ReadString ();
                var result = this.GetBuyIntent (arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
                if (result != null) { reply.WriteInt (1); result.WriteToParcel (reply, global::Android.OS.ParcelableWriteFlags.ReturnValue); } else reply.WriteInt (0);
                data.WriteInt (arg0);
                data.WriteString (arg1);
                data.WriteString (arg2);
                data.WriteString (arg3);
                data.WriteString (arg4);
                return true;
                }

            case TransactionGetPurchases: {
                data.EnforceInterface (descriptor);
                int arg0 = default (int);
                arg0 = data.ReadInt ();
                String arg1 = default (String);
                arg1 = data.ReadString ();
                String arg2 = default (String);
                arg2 = data.ReadString ();
                String arg3 = default (String);
                arg3 = data.ReadString ();
                var result = this.GetPurchases (arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
                if (result != null) { reply.WriteInt (1); result.WriteToParcel (reply, global::Android.OS.ParcelableWriteFlags.ReturnValue); } else reply.WriteInt (0);
                data.WriteInt (arg0);
                data.WriteString (arg1);
                data.WriteString (arg2);
                data.WriteString (arg3);
                return true;
                }

            case TransactionConsumePurchase: {
                data.EnforceInterface (descriptor);
                int arg0 = default (int);
                arg0 = data.ReadInt ();
                String arg1 = default (String);
                arg1 = data.ReadString ();
                String arg2 = default (String);
                arg2 = data.ReadString ();
                var result = this.ConsumePurchase (arg0, arg1, arg2);
                reply.WriteInt (result);
                data.WriteInt (arg0);
                data.WriteString (arg1);
                data.WriteString (arg2);
                return true;
                }

            }
            return base.OnTransact (code, data, reply, flags);
        }

        public class Proxy : Java.Lang.Object, Com.Android.Vending.Billing.IInAppBillingService
        {
            global::Android.OS.IBinder remote;

            public Proxy (global::Android.OS.IBinder remote)
            {
                this.remote = remote;
            }

            public global::Android.OS.IBinder AsBinder ()
            {
                return remote;
            }

            public string GetInterfaceDescriptor ()
            {
                return descriptor;
            }

            public int IsBillingSupported (int apiVersion, String packageName, String type)
            {
                global::Android.OS.Parcel __data = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();

                global::Android.OS.Parcel __reply = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();
int __result = default (int);

                try {
                    __data.WriteInterfaceToken (descriptor);
                    __data.WriteInt (apiVersion);
                    __data.WriteString (packageName);
                    __data.WriteString (type);
                    remote.Transact (IInAppBillingServiceStub.TransactionIsBillingSupported, __data, __reply, 0);
                    __reply.ReadException ();
                    __result = __reply.ReadInt ();

                } finally {
                    __reply.Recycle ();
                    __data.Recycle ();
                }
                return __result;

            }


            public global::Android.OS.Bundle GetSkuDetails (int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, global::Android.OS.Bundle skusBundle)
            {
                global::Android.OS.Parcel __data = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();

                global::Android.OS.Parcel __reply = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();
global::Android.OS.Bundle __result = default (global::Android.OS.Bundle);

                try {
                    __data.WriteInterfaceToken (descriptor);
                    __data.WriteInt (apiVersion);
                    __data.WriteString (packageName);
                    __data.WriteString (type);
                    if (skusBundle != null) { __data.WriteInt (1); skusBundle.WriteToParcel (__data, global::Android.OS.ParcelableWriteFlags.None); } else __data.WriteInt (0);
                    remote.Transact (IInAppBillingServiceStub.TransactionGetSkuDetails, __data, __reply, 0);
                    __reply.ReadException ();
                    __result = global::Android.OS.BundleStub.AsInterface (__reply.ReadStrongBinder ());

                } finally {
                    __reply.Recycle ();
                    __data.Recycle ();
                }
                return __result;

            }


            public global::Android.OS.Bundle GetBuyIntent (int apiVersion, String packageName, String sku, String type, String developerPayload)
            {
                global::Android.OS.Parcel __data = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();

                global::Android.OS.Parcel __reply = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();
global::Android.OS.Bundle __result = default (global::Android.OS.Bundle);

                try {
                    __data.WriteInterfaceToken (descriptor);
                    __data.WriteInt (apiVersion);
                    __data.WriteString (packageName);
                    __data.WriteString (sku);
                    __data.WriteString (type);
                    __data.WriteString (developerPayload);
                    remote.Transact (IInAppBillingServiceStub.TransactionGetBuyIntent, __data, __reply, 0);
                    __reply.ReadException ();
                    __result = global::Android.OS.BundleStub.AsInterface (__reply.ReadStrongBinder ());

                } finally {
                    __reply.Recycle ();
                    __data.Recycle ();
                }
                return __result;

            }


            public global::Android.OS.Bundle GetPurchases (int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, String continuationToken)
            {
                global::Android.OS.Parcel __data = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();

                global::Android.OS.Parcel __reply = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();
global::Android.OS.Bundle __result = default (global::Android.OS.Bundle);

                try {
                    __data.WriteInterfaceToken (descriptor);
                    __data.WriteInt (apiVersion);
                    __data.WriteString (packageName);
                    __data.WriteString (type);
                    __data.WriteString (continuationToken);
                    remote.Transact (IInAppBillingServiceStub.TransactionGetPurchases, __data, __reply, 0);
                    __reply.ReadException ();
                    __result = global::Android.OS.BundleStub.AsInterface (__reply.ReadStrongBinder ());

                } finally {
                    __reply.Recycle ();
                    __data.Recycle ();
                }
                return __result;

            }


            public int ConsumePurchase (int apiVersion, String packageName, String purchaseToken)
            {
                global::Android.OS.Parcel __data = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();

                global::Android.OS.Parcel __reply = global::Android.OS.Parcel.Obtain ();
int __result = default (int);

                try {
                    __data.WriteInterfaceToken (descriptor);
                    __data.WriteInt (apiVersion);
                    __data.WriteString (packageName);
                    __data.WriteString (purchaseToken);
                    remote.Transact (IInAppBillingServiceStub.TransactionConsumePurchase, __data, __reply, 0);
                    __reply.ReadException ();
                    __result = __reply.ReadInt ();

                } finally {
                    __reply.Recycle ();
                    __data.Recycle ();
                }
                return __result;

            }


        }

        internal const int TransactionIsBillingSupported = global::Android.OS.Binder.InterfaceConsts.FirstCallTransaction + 0;

        internal const int TransactionGetSkuDetails = global::Android.OS.Binder.InterfaceConsts.FirstCallTransaction + 1;

        internal const int TransactionGetBuyIntent = global::Android.OS.Binder.InterfaceConsts.FirstCallTransaction + 2;

        internal const int TransactionGetPurchases = global::Android.OS.Binder.InterfaceConsts.FirstCallTransaction + 3;

        internal const int TransactionConsumePurchase = global::Android.OS.Binder.InterfaceConsts.FirstCallTransaction + 4;

        public abstract int IsBillingSupported (int apiVersion, String packageName, String type);

        public abstract global::Android.OS.Bundle GetSkuDetails (int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, global::Android.OS.Bundle skusBundle);

        public abstract global::Android.OS.Bundle GetBuyIntent (int apiVersion, String packageName, String sku, String type, String developerPayload);

        public abstract global::Android.OS.Bundle GetPurchases (int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, String continuationToken);

        public abstract int ConsumePurchase (int apiVersion, String packageName, String purchaseToken);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding bundle.aidl   https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Bundle.aidl

You can look at https://github.com/prashantvc/InAppBillingDemo/tree/master/InAppService seems to be a good example on how to implement in app billing in Xamarin for Android

Comment: @DaveWolfe What do you have in obj folder in Bundle.cs generated file ? I have the same problem with Samsung In App AIDL files, but adding Bundle.aidl didn't help and generated Bundle.cs is just empty namespace. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, got id. I had Xamarin.Android 4.8.0, had to upgrade to 4.10.2 and add 'import android.os.Bundle;' to aidl file

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `Android.OS.BundleStub` whether we talk Xamarin API or native Android API.

Comment: After adding IInAppBillingService.aidl and rebuilding, IInAppBillingService.cs is generated by Xamarin Studio, and there are 4 lines like this:    global::Android.OS.BundleStub.AsInterface (data.ReadStrongBinder ());